# Customize the Javascript popup in Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a web application with Javascript and Amazon Cognito.  I have added the following code for Forgot Password

```
    cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('call result: ' + result);
           //Show login screen           
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        inputVerificationCode: function() {
            var verificationCode = prompt('Enter the code from email' ,'');
            var newPassword = prompt('Please enter new password ' ,'');
            cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
        }
    });
```

This works, but it shows crude old fashioned Javascript popups. Is there any way to customize this. I have seen the App UI customization option in the AWS console, but is that applicable for webapp integration as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a sample that invokes the prompt function from Javascript. It has no connection to Cognito UI customization. If you want to customize it, you can build your own modals that you display instead of the prompt invocation.